# I want to integrate paypal payment gateway to my application but i am not able to pass the amount variable

Tags: php, javascript

```
<button type="button" >total?</button>
<?php $abc= '<div id="output"></div>';
echo $abc;?>  
<form class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank" runat="server">    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Customer's First Name"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Customer's Last Name"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456" / >

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit Payment"/>
</form>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$('button').click(function() {

    var total = $(':checkbox:checked.case').get().reduce(function(total, checkbox) {
        return total + +checkbox.value;
    }, 0);

    $("#output").html(total);
});
</script>
```

The code contains a button that grabs the total sum from the checked answers. I need to pass this value to the payment gateway.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why not use `input type='text'` ?

Comment: could you add `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" id="amount">` to your paypal form and then right after `$("#output").html(total);` do -`$("#amount").val(total);`?

Answer (score 0):

You need another input for amount in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
```

Then, instead of `$('button').click` register form submit event like

```
$(function(){
    $('#paypal_form').on('submit', function(e){
        var total = 'get total here';
        if(!total) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        $(this).find("[name='amount']").val(total);
        return true;
    });
});
```